# Android - ListView issue with NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a 2 `EditText` which the user inputs into. Once the user clicks submit, the values are added to a `Listview` adapter. The values are separated using `StringTokenizer`. But a `NoSuchElementException` is caught when the first `EditText` is empty and app is `force closed`. So I included a `try-catch` and it didn't force close anymore. But now, the values which the user inputs in is not added to the row. Items are still added but there are no values. How do I solve this exception?

In short, after I added a `try-catch` for the exception, value in item are empty.

Adapter.java

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        }
        try
        {
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(noteList.get(position), ":");
        String first = tokens.nextToken();
        String second = tokens.nextToken();
        row.getTag();
        ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nametv)).setText(first);
        ((EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.result)).setText(second);
        }

        catch (NoSuchElementException f)
        {           

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catching the exception like this isn't the right approach - you can easily avoid it using `StringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()`.

For example, you might want something like:

```
String first = tokens.hasMoreTokens() ? tokens.nextToken() : "";
String second = tokens.hasMoreTokens() ? tokens.nextToken() : "";
```

That way you can deal *gracefully* with there being less input than you expect.

Now, the next line is simply:

```
row.getTag();
```

What's that meant to do? It's odd to call a `getXyz()` method and simply ignore the result - are you sure it's correct? It may be - I'm not an Android developer, so if it's common in Android then you can ignore this bit - but it's at least something I'd think about.